# Converting JSON to Array and getting the type

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a 2 part question.

1. How do I get my script to alert the variable `type` in javascript
   instead of  `[object object]`?
2. How do I get my Json to successfully convert to an Array without returning
   `NULL`?

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Arrays
var title = $('.table-item-1 > strong').map(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
        return value;
    }).get();

var name = $('[width|="23%"]').next('.table-item-1').map(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
        return value;
    }).get();

var phone = $('[width|="23%"]').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1').map(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
        return value;
    }).get();

var fax = $('[width|="23%"]').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1').map(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
        return value;
    }).get();

var email = $('[width|="23%"]').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1').next('.table-item-1 , a').map(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
        return value;
    }).get();

// Individual    
var brand = $('.panel-1 tr strong').html();
var corp = $('.panel-1 tr td :gt(0)').html();
var web = $('.panel-1 tr td ~ .focus :not(strong)').html();
var lna_code = $('.panel-1 tr td :last').html();
var lna_class = $('.panel-1 tr td :gt(4)').html();


var items = {
    'brand': brand,
    'corp': corp,
    'web': web,
    'lna_code': lna_code,
    'lna_class': lna_class,
    'title': title,
    'names': 
        name,
    'phones': 
        phone,
    'faxes': 
        fax,
    'emails': 
        email,
};

var data = $.toJSON(items);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/xxxxx/PHP/excel.php',
    data: {'data':data},
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    complete: function(data){
        alert(data); // alerts [object object] , want a string
   }
});

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['data'];
$result = json_decode($json);
$resultsType = gettype($result);
echo $resultsType;
?>
```

note: I'm using [json.js](https://sites.google.com/site/jollytoad/json.js?attredirects=0) for the `$.toJSON(items);` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the result to be an array on the PHP side, it should probably be an array on the javascript side:

```
[value1]
```

instead of

```
{key1 = value1}
```

what is happening in your code is you are instead creating an object. the object is probably what you actually want however as it does not seem like you have to iterate over the values on the PHP side, which would be the only reason for an actual array as opposed to an object.

if you leave the code as is, you access the values on the PHP side like so:

```
echo $result->brand;
```

Comment: Thanks, JSON was too much of a hassle to deal with. This made me realize I could do it without the conversion. I just redid my objects to [] in JS without keys and PHP is reading them as arrays. All good.

Comment: @Chamilyan do that if you like. can't imagine why you would prefer that over an object however. with an array you are dealing with anonymous data... with an object, you can reference specific data by name.